# Is there a limitation on the log lines in a travis build?

Tags: java, maven, github, travis-ci

I can see our Travis CI build jobs running until they logged 10000 lines and then the build seems to be stopped, no matter in which phase the build currently is.

Samples:
- https://travis-ci.org/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/jobs/64105164
- https://travis-ci.org/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/jobs/63968004
- https://travis-ci.org/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/jobs/63968003

I couldn't find anything about this constraint in the docs. Is there some undocumented limitation of how many lines you can log during a build?

Answer (score 8):

The log limit on Travis CI is 4 MB. The only workaround seems to be to produce less output.

https://twitter.com/travisci/status/174904509754118144

Comment: Oh, good to know. I reduced the build output to be < 10000 lines so hopefully we won't run into this issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a javascript error. In some situations we can see a red message fading in saying

> This log is too long to be displayed. Please reduce the verbosity of
>   your          build or download the

So the web view only displays the first 10k lines of the log output and we need to download the log to see the complete output.

Comment: The fact that the lines aren't displayed is no real limit. It's the 4MB limit that @PatrickOscity explained.